# Should users be allowed to edit tags or just delete them?

Tags: gui-design, interface, tags, tagging

I'm redesigning UI and features for tagging in a mobile app. The current implementation doesn't provide a way for users to directly edit or delete their existing tags.

Currently, tags that are not being used disappear from the tag list-view / cloud, which seems to be working. But this doesn't allow editing tags. (Editing tags is desirable, because the data we're collecting will be used longitudinally for data analysis, so helps to not break the data.)

Should there be a separate "tag management" area for editing tags? Can this be handled in within the tag-creation area?

The three thoughts I'm exploring are:

- pop-up to edit a tag
- separate area to manage tags (in 'settings')

Or am I setting myself up for trouble in a way I'm not foreseeing, and this is really the best option:

- don't allow editing, only deleting

Comment: There's quite a lot going on here. That's going to make it hard to give a single useful answer as there isn't just one specific answerable question here. (And we can't just list examples of something, that isn't really what a Q&A site is for). It seems like you're just after general advice, which is a bit broad. Can you reduce this down to one single answerable question? You're welcome to ask other questions on the same topic but one large broad post like this isn't really going to provide you with a useful answer as it stands.

Comment: I see what you mean. Should I delete and re-submit? I suppose the last sentence may be the most specific... looking for good examples to get ideas from. But maybe that's not the best use of this forum?

Comment: Examples of stuff aren't the best use of this site (because it's a Question and Answer site, not a Forum). Also, as the site is full of UX professionals / experts then you get the best answers if you explicitly ask to solve a problem. Asking for examples is like saying *'hey, UX experts, I want {something} but I won't ask you experts to give me the solution, I want you to point me to stuff other people have done so I can use their ideas instead'*. Just ask 'This is my issue, I've tried to address it by doing X, but what is a better way of doing it?' and us UX professionals can give the answer.

Comment: Apologies for my repeated questions, because I'm new to this Q&A site. I'm a UX professional myself (15 years), and I have edited the question above in a way that makes sense to me. Does it now make sense to you, in a way that you feel is suitable to this Q&A site?

Comment: Some questions from me: So can users create new tags if they want? Can users add and remove tags from the things-they-are-tagging at will? When you say delete tags, does that mean they delete the tag entirely, or just remove it from the item?

Comment: Sorry... copy/paste error... Users can create their own tags. Users can add and remove tags from the things-they-are-tagging (an "item") at will. It's easy for users to remove tags, but the desire is for users to delete tags entirely off the system to either: 1) replace a misspelled tag 2) delete a tag they wish they had never entered and will never use again. I'm using your distinction to "remove" (to un-tag an item) or "delete" (to remove it from being available in the system).

Comment: The easiest solution is to allow deleting a tag entirely off the system, but this creates a discontinuity in longitudinal data analysis. I'd like to avoid doing this via a 'settings' panel, but might practically end up there, due to the continuity issue. It just seems weird to have a pop-up for editing.

Comment: I hope you are talking about per-user tags here. E.g., if I created the tag "book", and another user creates the tag "book", the two will be independent from each other, and when I edit it to say "print media" because I also want to track magazines, others' entries won't be suddenly tagged "print entries" as well. If you have m:n relationships between users and tags, you shouldn't allow edits and deletions at all. Using the first schema is viable, but then you can't do that much data analysis, because the meaning of tags with the same name will differ between users.

Comment: Hi @RumiP. Yes, the editing/deleting would only be allowed for per-user tags. There will be un-editable/deletable system-wide tags. Can you define what you mean by "m:n relationships"? Our analysis is mostly per-user, within their own tag structure. It's not ideal if the user edits a tag, that's mostly ok for us. We are only identifying clusters based on their tags. So they will be incentivized to only edit tags towards the outcome/meaning they desire in the analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are usually deleted and not edited. I usually advocate editing. However, since tags are so short, it simplifies the interface to only allow deleting. As a result, this may have become the convention.

If you do want to allow editing, replace the delete ('X') icon with an edit icon and allow deletion in edit mode (after the edit icon click).

I'm not too clear on how you are using the tagging data. Keep in mind that though the user deletes the tag, it does not mean that the system no longer has that data. The data should maintain deleted tag entries and have a means of differentiating them (by using negative numbers for example).

Comment: "If you do want to allow editing, replace the delete ('X') icon with an edit icon and allow deletion in edit mode (after the edit icon click)." Thanks for that :) Yes, the user would only delete the tag from inside the interface, but the system should still have it, or its versions, if the editing is allowed.